# Unable to auto load a template in Tinymce Editor when Tinymce loads

Tags: javascript, tinymce

Custom templates are working fine in my TinyMce editor if I have to insert it from the template icon in the toolbar. But how can I auto load a custom template directly when TinyMce loads

```
            templates: [
            { title: 'Test22', description: 'A cure for writers block', content: 'Once upon a time...' }
            ],
            template : 'Test22', // this line does not load the template on Tinymce onload
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no event/API to do insert a template on page load.  You can use the `setContent()` API to load content when the editor is first loaded.

You could put something like this in your TinyMCE configuration:

```
setup: function (editor) {
    editor.on('init', function (e) {
       // You can load whatever content you want - this is just a hardcoded example...
       editor.setContent('<p>This is the content in TinyMCE!</p>');
    });
}
```

Comment: thank you for the prompt reply, but i am unable to add the code you provided, where exactly do i put it ?  also found the below code ... will this work ... ?  tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand('mceInsertTemplate', false, 'Test22');

Comment: oops sorry ...your code is working now ....  is there a way .. this will work ? tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand('mceInsertTemplate', false, 'TemplateName');

Comment: No - there is no way to insert a template by name via the API.